# Why does my Android program crash when I access the Orientation sensor (HTC Desire)?

Tags: java, android

So I am playing around with the Android api, and am trying to figure out how to get the heading the phone is pointing towards.

I have the following code:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAcceller;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    checkNotNull(mSensorManager);
    try {
        mAcceller = mSensorManager.getSensorList(3).get(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast(e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

But when I try to run it on my phone I just get a message that the program has crashed. When I run it in the emulator it tells me that there are no sensors (thats to be expect, but it means I can't test the code).

Does anybody know how to work around this issue? I know the error happens in the try statement because if I comment it out, the program runs.

*Edit*: It turns out that I am an idiot, the crash happened when I null refered somewhere else in my code, as a response to getting a notification that the sensor had been turned on.

Dave if you upgrade your comment to an answer, I will mark that as accepted (since I found the problem as soon as I figured out how the debugger worked).

Comment: Run the code on your phone, and get the logcat output of the error.  Then post the stacktrace here.

Comment: Getting arbitrary indexes from a Collection generally isn't a good idea without first checking to see if the index exists.

Answer (score 0):

First, the orientation sensor is deprecated.

Second, use a `Sensor` `TYPE_` constant rather than your own integers. For example:

```
mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

Comment: You are right, but doing either would have let to more complicated sample code and aren't necessary (it only has to run on my phone to debug it, and it has one sensor).